# Asynchronous enqueue of the Google Maps API

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, google-maps

I am loading the Google Maps API on a lot of Wordpress sites and I have always added it with an enqueue. Lately, we have been getting the following warning on the console:

"*Google Maps JavaScript API has been loaded directly without loading=async. This can result in suboptimal performance*."

So we have been researching ways to get this script loaded in an asynchronous way. We've found on the following blog post the discussion about async/defer being added to Wp 6.3 enqueues:

https://make.wordpress.org/core/2023/07/14/registering-scripts-with-async-and-defer-attributes-in-wordpress-6-3/

I am adding the Google Maps API like this then:

```
wp_register_script(
    'google-api-key',
    'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=' . MAPS_API_KEY . '&callback=Function.prototype',
    array(),
    null,
    array(
        'in_footer' => true,
        'strategy'  => 'async',
    )
);
wp_enqueue_script('google-api-key');
```

This seems to work as it does add the following to the script tag:

async="async" data-wp-strategy="async"

But the warning persists. Is it a false positive now that the script tag actually has the async attribute?

Comment: If you're using a server-side cache, have you cleared the cache?

Comment: Yes, that doesn't seem to be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your URL when calling the google API:
**&loading=async**